# Optimizing JMS listeners in Spring

Tags: spring, performance, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I've got a queue in ActiveMQ. There are 2 consumers using 2 different selectors. The problem is that messages are produced much faster that being consumed.

I'm using Spring Boot ActiveMQ starter with the default configuration with `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. The only thing I've found for tuning it so far is `DefaultMessageListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency`. Currently it is set to `2-4` but increasing it even to `10-50` still doesn't resolve the problem though performing somewhat better.

I wonder what are the best practices of configuring JMS listeners in Spring? How can I tune its performance?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: ok "The problem is that messages are produced much faster that being consumed." for you but what do you want exactly in addition to use DMLC Concurrency?

Comment: @Hassen Bennour maybe a faster `ConnectionFactory`, maybe a faster `MessageConverter`, any kind of such things

Comment: try https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setIdleTaskExecutionLimit-int-

Comment: Raise this limit if you encounter too frequent scaling up and down. With this limit being higher, an idle consumer will be kept around longer, avoiding the restart of a consumer once a new load of messages comes in. Alternatively, specify a higher "maxMessagesPerTask" and/or "receiveTimeout" value, which will also lead to idle consumers being kept around for a longer time (while also increasing the average execution time of each scheduled task).

Comment: maybe the solution is to refactor your consumer ??

Comment: Tuning JMS Message Consumption In Spring
 https://bsnyderblog.blogspot.be/2010/05/tuning-jms-message-consumption-in.html

Comment: @Hassen Bennour ok, thanks you very much, I'm trying it right now. Also, what do you know about `sessionTransacted` property? May it be helpful?

Comment: sessionTransacted if not needed dont use it because this is consume more resources

Comment: @Hassen Bennour I've used the following configuration but it doesn't help. Maybe you can suggest what I'm doing wrong? Here the gist https://gist.github.com/dmitrysenkovich/9eedf252504a94d2a8ec2bcfc89315e5

Comment: nothing special, try with factory.setIdleTaskExecutionLimit(100) and take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

Comment: @Hassen Bennour hmmm, that doesn't seem do have such a method..

Comment: current version have and some latest versions too  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setIdleTaskExecutionLimit-int-

Comment: @Hassen Bennour sorry, but I've got `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` in the gist not `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you can manage more properties by defining the DefaultMessageListenerContainer like setIdleTaskExecutionLimit

Comment: @HassenBennour seems like I have to use `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` because of using `JmsListener` annotation. I can't find a way to cast it somehow

Comment: in the bean definition businessEventsListenerFactory you can override anonymously the initializeContainer method 
     DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory(){
      @Override
      protected void initializeContainer(DefaultMessageListenerContainer container) {
       super.initializeContainer(container);
       container.setIdleTaskExecutionLimit(1000);
      }
     };